# Count value in an object needs array PHP

Tags: php, json, collections, count, laravel-6

I have an Array like below, is there any way to count the total number of occurrences of CID.
For example:

**CID = 992010000021102**

I want to count the result as **2**

**- Laravel 6, php 7.4**

```json
{
    "status": true,
    "message": null,
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "cid": "99201000021102",
                "mailaddress": "99201000021102@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "cid": "99201000021105",
                "mailaddress": "99201000021105@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "cid": "00003900062153",
                "mailaddress": "00003900062153@designone.jp"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "cid": "99201000021102",
                "mailaddress": "99201000021102@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "cid": "99201000021101",
                "mailaddress": "99201000021101@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I tried running the loops but the result is not as expected.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Close these kind of questions quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```php
$countArr = [];
foreach ($arr as $val){
    foreach ($val as $value){
        if (!array_key_exists($value['cid'], $countArr)){
            $countArr[$value['cid']] = 1;
        }else $countArr[$value['cid']] += 1;
    }
}
print_r($countArr);
```

It will print:

```php
Array
(
    [99201000021102] => 2
    [99201000021105] => 1
    [00003900062153] => 1
    [99201000021101] => 1
)
```

Because in each array in the main array we have some objects, we need the nested loop. Each time we check if that `CID` exist in the final array if yes, we sum the occurrence with 1 otherwise we will push new `CID` with the occurrence of 1.

Answer (score 0):

To count the total number of occurrences of a specific value in an array, you can use a loop to iterate through the array and increment a counter variable each time the value is found. For example in your case..

```
$array = [
    [
        [
            "cid" => "99201000021102",
            "mailaddress" => "hainghia.developer@gmail.com"
        ],
        [
            "cid" => "99201000021105",
            "mailaddress" => "thiendi@gmail.com"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "cid" => "00003900062153",
            "mailaddress" => "sawaya.keiichiro@designone.jp"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "cid" => "99201000021102",
            "mailaddress" => "hainghia.developer@gmail.com"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "cid" => "99201000021101",
            "mailaddress" => "kankocho_auth@gmail.com"
        ]
    ]
];

$cid = "99201000021102";
$count = 0;

foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $innerItem) {
        if ($innerItem['cid'] == $cid) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}

echo $count; // Outputs 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your result in jQuery also,
Try this.

```js
var json = {
    "status": true,
    "message": null,
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "cid": "99201000021102",
                "mailaddress": "99201000021102@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "cid": "99201000021105",
                "mailaddress": "99201000021105@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "cid": "00003900062153",
                "mailaddress": "00003900062153@designone.jp"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "cid": "99201000021102",
                "mailaddress": "99201000021102@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "cid": "99201000021101",
                "mailaddress": "99201000021101@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    ]
};
var testOp = getKeys(json,"99201000021102");
alert('Serach result found no of time : '+testOp);
function getKeys(obj, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getKeys(obj[i], val));
        } else if (obj[i] == val) {
            objects.push(i);
        }
    }
    return objects.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use [collection helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections) of Laravel on your data array, pretty simple
- Convert you data array to collection and flatten 1 level and groupBy "cid" column

  $collectionResult = collect($data)->flatten(1)->groupBy('cid');
- **$data** variable is data array get from your response, and flatten need to be done as per your data set from your data we need to apply only one level flatten to get data as stream to group By properly.
- Print output result, you will get your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$count = count(
    array_filter(
        $yourarray->data,
        function($v) {
            return $v[0]->cid === '99201000021102';
        }
    )
);
```

Explanation:

- `$v[0]->cid` is compared against the value we search for the value
- we have a `function` that's passed as the second parameter to `array_filter` which will determine which items would end up in the result, while `$yourarray->data` is passed as the first parameter
- the result of `array_filter` is an array that contains the items for which the `function` was `true` and nothing else
- using `count` we get the number of elements in the filtered array

Additionally, if you do not know the value to search for in advance, use the `use` specification, like

```
$a = '99201000021102';
$count = count(
    array_filter(
        $yourarray->data,
        function($v) use ($a) {
            return $v[0]->cid === $a;
        }
    )
);
```